# SQL Server 2008 Beginner Script Question On effecting all rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scripting

I'm useing SQL Server 2008 and I have a small script to split a row of data into several different columns. My question is how do I get the script to effect all the rows in the column? Right now the data row is just a string literal. I'm wondering if there is another way to wright this so I do not have to keep replaceing the DATA ROW EXAMPLE line with each rows data. The script is below.

```
DECLARE @TEXTINPUT VARCHAR(120)

SET @TEXTINPUT = 'DATA ROW EXAMPLE 12 89564 DATA ROW EXAMPLE'

SELECT @TEXTINPUT AS TEXTINPUT

SELECT SUBSTRING(@TEXTINPUT,1,4) AS UNIT,
  SUBSTRING(@TEXTINPUT,6,3) AS NAME,
  SUBSTRING(@TEXTINPUT,10,7) AS ACCOUNT,
  SUBSTRING(@TEXTINPUT,18,2) AS NOTE


INSERT INTO ExampleTable
(UNIT, NAME, ACCOUNT, NOTE)
VALUES (SUBSTRING(@TEXTINPUT,1,4), SUBSTRING(@TEXTINPUT,6,3), SUBSTRING(@TEXTINPUT,10,7),
SUBSTRING(@TEXTINPUT,18,2))
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume below the table with source data is called `SourceTable` and the column you are splitting is called `SourceCol`

```
INSERT INTO ExampleTable
(UNIT, NAME, ACCOUNT, NOTE)
SELECT SUBSTRING(SourceCol,1,1) AS UNIT,
  SUBSTRING(SourceCol,3,9) AS NAME,
  SUBSTRING(SourceCol,13,6) AS ACCOUNT,
  SUBSTRING(SourceCol,20,3) AS NOTE
 FROM SourceTable
```

Comment: You just answered my stupid question. Select, From, Where, I have to remember that. Thank You!

Comment: Yep, Three quite vital clauses!

Comment: LOL! Yep I feel like a morron!